# Implementing Google's hashbang/Ajax crawl with Jruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo, jruby, htmlunit, watij

Working from here: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174992

An html snapshot of the page is advised for indexing.  How can I do this with watij?  With htmlunit?

Comment: Was there a resolution to this? I'm looking to do the same via rails.

Comment: Actually, yes! See below, and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

https://gist.github.com/3702913

Basically, we use capybara to load and then render the page.  Simple.

I tried WebSpec and HtmlUnit first, but didn't have as much luck.  (Then again, JRuby can complicate things.)